# Shared memory - need for synchronization

Tags: c++, windows, concurrency, shared-memory

I've seen a project where communication between processes was made using shared memory (e.g. using `::CreateFileMapping` under Windows) and every time one of the processes wanted to notify that some data is available in shared memory, a synchronization mechanism using named events notified the interested party that the content of the shared memory changed.

I am concerned on the fact that the appropriate memory fences are not present for the process that reads the new information to know that it has to invalidate it's copy of the data and read it from main memory once it is "published" by the producer process.

Do you know how can this be accomplished on Windows using shared memory?

**EDIT**
Just wanted to add that after creating the file mapping the processes uses MapViewOfFile() API only once and every new modification to the shared data uses the pointer obtained by the initial call to MapViewOfFile() to read the new data sent over the shared memory. Does correct synchronization require that every time data changes in shared memory the process that reads data must create MapViewOfFile() every time ?

Comment: To be a valid synchronization mechanism, named events should have proper memory fences in place. Do you have evidence that this might not happen?

Comment: @Alexey: Indeed, it's usually the case, but is it guaranted by standard/specs/etc.?

Comment: On windows one can use CreateEvent api for synchronization. I don't know if setting and waiting for that event produces the aquire/release necessary mem fences though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use a Windows Named Event for signaling changes, then everything should be OK.

Process A changes the data and calls `SetEvent`.

Process B waits for the event using `WaitForSingleObject` or similar, and sees that it is set.

Process B then reads the data. `WaitForSingleObject` contains all the necessary synchronization to ensure that the changes made by process A before the call to `SetEvent` are read by process B.

Of course, if you make any changes to the data **after** calling `SetEvent`, then these may or may not show up when process B reads the data.

If you don't want to use Events, you could use a Mutex created with `CreateMutex`, or you could write lock-free code using the `Interlocked...` functions such as `InterlockedExchange` and `InterlockedIncrement`.

However you do the synchronization, you do not need to call `MapViewOfFile` more than once.

Answer (score 6):

What you're looking for for shared memory on windows is the InterlockedExchange function.  See the [msdn article here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The REALLY important part is quoted:

> This function generates a full memory barrier (or fence) to ensure
>   that memory operations are completed in order.

This will function cross-process.  I've worked with it before, and found it 100% reliable for implementing a mutex-like construct on top of shared memory.

How you do that is that you exchange it with the "set" value.  If you get "clear" back, you have it (it was clear), but if you get "set" back, then somebody else had it.  You loop, sleep between looping, etc, until you "get" it.  Basically this:

```
#define LOCK_SET 1
#define LOCK_CLEAR 0

int* lock_location = LOCK_LOCATION; // ensure this is in shared memory
if (InterlockedExchange(lock_location, LOCK_SET) == LOCK_CLEAR)
{
    return true; // got the lock
}
else
{
    return false; // didn't get the lock
}
```

As above, and loop until you "get" it.

Comment: So I have a mutex implementation here could use a named win critical section either but how to use this on producer and consumers processes?

Comment: Your question was how to make a synchronization mechanism in shared memory.  This will allow you to do exactly that.  From here, you can design your own set of counters, or other variables protected by this in shared memory.  If you don't know how to implement such by yourself, you need to read up a bit on the basics of synchronization.  But if all you needed was producer consumer, I'd be looking into named pipes or sockets or other interprocess communication.  Shared memory is not always the best choice for simple problems.

Comment: I only need to know what guarantees platform offers for what I need

Comment: What I quoted from the MSDN article is the guarantee that two processes pointing to the same shared memory, if used through this function, it will be atomic.  And I've done it myself (this isn't "in theory" code, it's in production).  I don't know what more you want.

Comment: just a solution to the asked question tnx for support

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution @KevinAnderson. Just thought I'd point out that to do this, all processes that are using the Named Shared Memory will need read-write access (and the equivalent permissions - e.g. if the namespace is under ``Global\``). If this is a deal-breaker, you might need to stick to named mutexes or some other method.

Comment: So it's faster than using Mutex or Semaphore?

Comment: Is it possible to use it when one process is in Java and the other is in Python?

Answer (score 1):

Let's call process A the data producer and process B the data consumer. Until now, you have a mechanism for process A to notify process B that new data has been produced. I suggest you created a reverse notification (from B to A) which tells process A that the data has been consumed. If, for performance reason, you don't want process A to wait for the data to be consumed, you could set up a [ring-buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_buffer) in the shared memory.

Comment: Yes, but how can a be sure data publication is seen by the consumers?

Comment: @Ghita By default, the x86 architecture is cache coherent. Writes made by one processor are always seen by subsequent reads, either by the same, or other processors of the same system. All you have to do is ensure that the compiler calls the notification function after data has been written to shared memory. I think you are supposed to mark memory as "volatile" (in C) to guarantee this.

Comment: Well I think reordering is possible even on x86 for performance

Comment: @Ghita IIRC, the x86 architecture uses the [MESI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol) protocol for cache coherency. Before writing a memory "region" (i.e., a cache line), a processor needs to own it. A processor is only allowed to read a cache line, if it is the owner or if the cache line has no owner.